# Adding an array to a MySQL column in SELECT

Tags: php, mysql, select

I have an array with as set of users and their respective karma:

```
$some_array = Array
(
    [user_id] => Array
        (
            [0] => 4
            [1] => 3
            [2] => 5
            [3] => 1
        )

    [karma] => Array
        (
            [0] => 129
            [1] => 87
            [2] => 13
            [3] => 20
        )

)
```

I was wondering if, when you are retrieving the user data from a MySQL table, you can add an extra column with the karma array and order by that extra_column:

```
 $query = 'SELECT user.*, {{$some_array['karma'] as extra_column}} WHERE
 user.id IN '.(implode(',',$some_array['user_id'])).' ORDER BY extra_column';
```

Any ideas? Is it possible?

Comment: Do you want that extra column to be only in your result of the SELECT? The values in the array are not in the database?

Comment: I would have to agree with Eric. Maybe there is another solution where you can use a table to store some data or do some sort of calculation after the sql results are returned. Are you trying to associate the array with the result, or individual array items to row numbers?

Comment: actually, just the individual array to the row numbers... and @True Soft, these karma calculations change according to the user who is viewing them and when he is viewing them, thats why I don't see why I should store it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT  id, ELT(FIELD(id, 4, 3, 5, 1), 129, 87, 13, 20) AS karma
FROM    (
        SELECT  4 AS id
        UNION ALL
        SELECT  3 AS id
        UNION ALL
        SELECT  5 AS id
        UNION ALL
        SELECT  1 AS id
        ) q
WHERE   id IN (4, 3, 5, 1)
ORDER BY
        karma
```

Comment: I didn't know these functions existed.  That's a much cleaner solution than my case statement.

Comment: it worked! but somehow after I removed the (SELECT... UNION ALL) stuff... before it was showing all the users in the user_table.

Comment: oh, and I wanted to thank everyone for the interest... this website really rocks!

Answer (score 1):

Not really (at least not without going through some really nasty dynamic sql generation).

You would have to have the karma in a column on the user table (or some other table that you could join to the user table).  It seems like that should be stored in the database anyways though right?

Answer (score 1):

If the values in the array have to be provided by the script (i.e., don't exist in the database in any way you could join them, which is the ideal case), then I see two possibilities:

1. Create a temporary table for your karma, insert all karma values, and then join your query with your karma array
2. Use a case statement in your query.  This is an untenable solution if the number of users is large.

The code for generating the case statement could look something like this:

```
$query = 'SELECT *, ' . GenerateCaseStatement($some_array) . ' AS extra_column FROM user WHERE user.id in (' . implode(',', $some_array['user_id']) . ' ORDER BY extra_column';

function GenerateCaseStatement($some_array)
{
    $str = 'CASE id ';
    for (i=0; i<array_len($some_array['user_id']); ++i)
    {
        $str .= ' WHEN ' . (int)($some_array['user_id'][i]) . ' THEN ' . (int)($some_array['karma'][i]);
    }
    $str .= ' ELSE NULL END';
    return $str;
}
```